# React listen to global Object callback

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm working on an SDK. It currently supports JavaScript however it needs to support React (& possibly Vue/Angular down the road).

It first loads the SDK via a script. Then modifies an element with the `sdk-id`. The user interacts with the element and the SDK fires a callback, `AppNameSDK.callback(data)`. This all works fine on vanilla javascript however for React I'm having trouble figuring out how to call a callback within the React Component.

In short. How can I either
A) Call a React Components function/method from an externally loaded Object
or
B) Change an externally loaded objects function via a React Component

Example of Vanilla Code (no problems)

```
<div 
  id="sdk-id" 
  data-foo="foo" 
  data-bar="bar">
</div>
<script src="https://example.com/sdk/v1/client-id"></script>
// Loads obj called AppNameSDK
<script type="text/javascript">
AppNameSDK.callback = (data) => {
    console.log("data",data)
}
</script>
```

Example of React Code (cannot access callback)

```
import React,{useEffect} from 'react';

const useScript = (url,loadFunc,errorFunc) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    const script = document.createElement('script');
    script.src = url;
    script.async = true;
    document.body.appendChild(script);
    script.addEventListener('load', function () {
      if(loadFunc !== undefined && typeof loadFunc === "function"){
        loadFunc();
      }
    });
    script.addEventListener('error', function (e) {
      console.log();
      if(errorFunc !== undefined && typeof errorFunc === "function"){
        errorFunc();
      }
    });

    return () => {
      if(document.body.contains(script)){
        document.body.removeChild(script);
      }
    }
  }, [url,loadFunc,errorFunc]);
};

const Test = () => {

  let scriptSrc = "https://example.com/sdk/v1/client-id";
  useScript(scriptSrc);

  // Need to figure out how to call this function
  const callback = (data) => {
    console.log("data",data);
  }

  return (
    <div className="test">
      <h3>Test Component</h3>
      <div 
        id="sdk-id" 
        data-foo={"foo"} 
        data-bar={"bar"}>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Test;
```